# Running A command within a function Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I'm at a loss here.  I'm trying to create a script to automate some things.  I have a function **exitfn()** it is supposed to catch the **ctrl+c** and execute. I do this because, if you look, below the function this operation sometimes hangs and I only need to run it. It does not finish so I tell the ask the user to hit ctrl+c and it should run the function but instead I get back:

> /bin/grep: /var/lib/mrtg/cfgs/ .cfg: No such file or directory.

My thoughts:

- Is it even running the first comman correctly?
- Am I using the whole trap thing wrong?

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  echo "Enter the name of the device: > "
  read dName
  echo "Now enter device type [cpu, ram, : > "
  read dType
  echo "Enter the devices actual value with % symbol: > "
  read aValue
  echo "Enter the desired threshold with % symbol: > " 
  read dValue
  echo "Grounding..." 
  n=`locate thresholdHandler.pl`
  cd ${n%thresholdHandler.pl}
  echo "Hit Ctrl+C to continue......"

  exitfn() {
      trap SIGINT
      echo; 
          echo "Running second command, wait 3 seconds"  
          sleep 3
          ./thresholdHandler.pl output above $dname.$dType $dValue $aValue
          echo "Complete"
      exit
  }

  trap "exitfn" INT
  ./thresholdHandler.pl output above $dName.$dType $aValue $dValue
  sleep 10
  trap SIGINT
  ```

Thank You for your time.

Comment: What's the extra `fi` in the end?

Comment: I removed that the issue was still not resolved. I will reflect this on my original post.

Comment: What does the perl script do ?

Comment: The pl script is not the issue the first one works and the second one is only a variation.

Comment: oh, I didn't see the comments before posting my answer. Do you want to force the execution of the script with different param if you catch CTRL + C ?

Comment: Yes, I want it to run the first one then when I hit CTRL+C I want it to stop what it's doing and execute the variation of the script.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought :) I edited my original answer to address this point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `trap` way too much in your script :)

Your code should look like this :

```
echo "Hit Ctrl+C to continue......"

exitfn() {
    trap "" SIGINT    #we trap any further ctrl + c and force execution of exitfn
    echo; 
        echo "Running second command, wait 3 seconds"  
        sleep 3
        ./thresholdHandler.pl output above $dName.$dType $dValue $aValue
        echo "Complete"
    exit 0
}

trap "exitfn" SIGINT    #here, only ctrl+c is trapped. Add more signals here if needed
./thresholdHandler.pl output above $dName.$dType $aValue $dValue
sleep 10
```

Generally speaking, the correct usage of trap is `trap "instructions" SIGNAL[S]`. Once you put that line in your script, the trap will be active for all the instructions below (the ones before won't trigger your trap).

If you want to force-wait the execution of your perl script in your exit function, just trap the SIGINT and execute nothing.

Concerning your 1st point, yes, `thresholdHandler.pl` will be run. However, it will be run 2 times if you hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (once by the regular script, though not fully as it is interupted by SIGINT, and once by the exitfn when it is called by the trap), with different values (I don't know if this is intended or a simple typo in copying the exmaple).

Comment: I only want the one below to run for a few seconds then you cancel out then the second one runs till end.

Comment: @KirsKringle so, you want the 1st script executed for 10 seconds, then interupted, then wait for the user to press ctrl+c, then run the exit function ?

Comment: Essentially what you have is exactly what I want. Just think of the pl script being some sort of auditing thing.  The first one runs and runs sometimes, but the user knows that it does that and that it does not need to so they go ahead and cancel it.